# Create form in wp admin dashboard and save data in custom created db

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to create form of field text input and file input in WordPress admin dashboard and save the data in custom created table in database.

```
function certificate_fields() { ?>
    <h2>Fill the details</h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        Enter your code : <input type="text" name="s_code" placeholder="Enter Code"><br /><br />
        Upload Certificate image : <input type="file" name="s_image"><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Details">
    </form>
<?php }
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: have you tried any thing!

Comment: yeah i have tried

Comment: function certificate_fields() {
 ?>
 <h2>Fill the details</h2>
 
<form method="post" action="options.php">
  Enter your code : <input type="text" name="s_code" placeholder="Enter Code"></br></br>
  Upload Certificate image : <input type="file" name="s_image"></br></br> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit Details">  
</form>
this i have created form in backend

Comment: how i save this in custom table named "search_code"

Answer (score -1):

Before posting do some simple google search atleast. 
First Create a plugin and add an Admin option Page. Create a form.
Anyways, here are some references;

https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/06/wordpress-plugin-part-1/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages